# Copying arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I think doing `arraylist1=arraylist2` makes the 2 of them share the same memory. How can I copy an arraylist without them doing that? I want to treat them sepparately.

```
 List<Integer> rez = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Integer> rezc = new ArrayList<>();

        rez.add(1);
        rezc=rez;
         rezc.add(2);
        for (int s : rez) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }//this will print 1 2
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of ArrayList? Look at its constructors. Look at the addAll() method.

Comment: the addAll() might do the work.

Comment: @LuisAlberto: With the variables as declared in the question, using `clone` involves some ugly casting, probably not a great choice.

Comment: @JBNizet Will do from now on before asking questions. But this way it's a bit easier for me. People also get easy rep and I get faster and concise answers with great examples :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think doing arraylist1=arraylist2 makes the 2 of them share the same memory.

Not quite, it makes both of those *references* refer to the same, single, object.

> How can I copy an arraylist without them doing that?

Lots of options:

1. `ArrayList` has a [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29):

   ```
   List<Integer> rezc = new ArrayList<>(rez);
   ```
2. `List` has an [`addAll` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

   ```
   List<Integer> rezc = new ArrayList<>();
   rezc.addAll(rez);
   ```
3. `ArrayList` has a [`clone` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29), but it's a bit ugly to use if `rez` is declared as a `List` because you have to assume it's an `ArrayList` and cast it, which is probably not a great idea:

   ```
   List<Integer> rezc = (List<Integer>)((ArrayList<Integer>)rez).clone();
   ```

It's well worth reading through the JavaDoc when trying to figure things like this out.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `arraylist1=arraylist2` means they are referring to same ArrayList object. Reference variables `arraylist1` and `arraylist2` are referring to same object and hence, the changes done by `arraylist1` will be seen when you are trying to access the object by `arraylist2`

If you want to make a new ArrayList then, `ArrayList rezc = new ArrayList(rez)`

Comment: But how can I make them 2 different things?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line `rezc=rez;`

Use `List<Integer> rezc = new ArrayList<>(rez);`

Answer (score 1):

The long hand way is a for loop to cycle though one list while adding all the items to the second. Something like

```
for (int I = 0; I < rez.size() I++) {
    rezc.add(rez.get(I)); }
```

But the previous answers are much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are talking about Java shallow cloning v/s deep cloning. In this case the below code might help

```
List<Integer> rez = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> rezc = new ArrayList<>();
rez.add(1);
rezc.addAll(rez); // addAll
List<Integer> rezc2 = (List<Integer>)((ArrayList<Integer>)rez).clone(); //clone
```